export default new TypeScript Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554) how to fix?
Doing a QA job with PlayWright and TypeScript
Trying to avoid extra imports like defaultPage = new defaultPage(page); in spec files just to reduce lines of code and make tests little more pretty.
new DefaultPage() underlined with Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554) It is because constructor has a argument page: Page and export looking for argument too, but I can't figure out what exact argument it is asking for?

import { Page, Locator } from '@playwright/test';
import { basePage } from "../defaultPeage";

export class DefaultPage extends extraPage {

    readonly page: Page;
    readonly defaultButton: Locator;
  
    constructor(page: Page) {
      super(page);
      this.page = page;
      this.defaultButton = page.locator("[type='default']");
    }
}

export default new DefaultPage(); // <- Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554) under new DefaultPage()

if remove arg from constructor or rename file to JS error is disappear, but it is definitely not the way. Tried to add all imaginable arguments to Default Page() but nothing helps

Fix should be obvious: new DefaultPage(page). Usually the importing module will call the constructor through, so just export the class. What is your intent?

You're trying to export an instance of DefaultPage and you're not provided anything to the constructor despite it having a page: Page argument that is required.
Either mark this argument as optional so you can instantiate it with no arguments (new DefaultPage()), or simply delegate the instantiation to where you actually need the object where you can safely provide an actual value for page.
